# Angular 2 when to use controls[] and when to use get() in FormControl

Tags: angular

When I look at tutorials about Angular's forms, I see some people using `form.controls['key']` to access the FormControl, while others use `form.get('key')` to do so.

Which one should I use, and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to documentation `get()` method can take 2 types of parameters:

`get(path: Array<string | number> | string)`, so you may pass full path of you nested form control to `.get()` method in this ways:

`this.form.get('person.name');`
`this.form.get(['person', 'name']);`

If you directly access to `[controls]` - you can get only first-level nested control element and risk to get `'can not read property 'formElementName' of undefined` error if you try do get deeper nested element: `form['element1']['element2']` <- error if `element1` doesn't exist .

As for me - using get() method is more convenient, especially if you want to generate path to necessary form-control in your code.